# How to search for other iPhone/iPod devices on network and then connect to them

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me how to search for available iPhone/iPod devices on a network in an iPhone application. I mean I want to connect to available iPhone/iPod devices on a network in one of my application.

Thanks in advance

Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CocoaTouch/GameKit/index.html) and [`GKSession`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Bonjour" in the developer examples.